# Keras Model doesn't accept input_layer

Tags: r, python-2.7, deep-learning, keras

I am a newbie to Deep Learning, and am trying to build a model in R using Keras.  I have 20,000 32x32x3 images stored in an array for model training.When I run:

```
model = keras_model_sequential()
model %>% layer_input(shape = c(32,32,3))
```

I get the following error :

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Sequential'

Detailed traceback: 
File "/home/abhijit331/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/keras/python/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1380, in Input
input_tensor=tensor)
File "/home/abhijit331/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/keras/python/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1287, in __init__
name=self.name)
File "/home/abhijit331/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/keras/python/keras/backend.py", line 545, in placeholder
x = array_ops.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
File "/home/abhijit331/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1499, in placeholder
shape = tensor_shape.as_shape(shape)
File "/home/abhijit331/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 80
```

can anyone help me figure out how to setup an input layer for my model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Sequential API you don't use the `layer_input` function. 
Your first layer will need to have an `input_shape` argument that will act as `layer_input`. For example:

```
model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 32, input_shape = c(784)) %>%
  layer_activation('relu') %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 10) %>% 
  layer_activation('softmax')
```

You can use the `layer_input` function when using the Functional API. See more [here](https://rstudio.github.io/keras/articles/functional_api.html).